# Expression in responseValidator in http:request in mule

Tags: mule4

I use `mule-http-connector` version `1.6.0` in mule 4.4 community edition (MuleSoft 4 ce) and I get a response (aka GraphQL):

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "data": ...
}
```

I want validate the response by cheking success field. I can made validation by use two…four components (`http:response`, `choice`, `raise`…), but I found in Anypoint Studio 7.11 in component properties «Reponse» → «Response validator» → «Expression or Bean reference». I don't want use «Bean reference» and write java code, but I want use «Expression». I wrote that:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.success
```

But I got error:

> ```
> "org.mule.weave.v2.exception.UnexpectedFunctionCallTypesException: You called the function 'Value Selector' with these arguments: 
>   1: Binary ("" as Binary {base: "64"})
>   2: Name ("success")
> ```

If I write something:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
true
```

I got that error:

> ```
> org.mule.weave.v2.exception.WriterExecutionException: Unable to convert 'true' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class 'ResponseValidator'
>
> 4| true
>    ^^^^
> Trace:
>   at anonymous::main (line: 4, column: 1), while writing Java at 
> 4| true
>    ^^^^.
>
> 4| true
>    ^^^^
> Trace:
>   at anonymous::main (line: 4, column: 1)
> " evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
> output application/json
> ---
> true".
> ```

How to write a dw expression in a response validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how response validation should be used. By default -when using a string- it validates HTTP status codes against ranges of status codes in the string. If you want to implement your custom validation you have to extend Java class org.mule.extension.http.api.request.validator.RangeStatusCodeValidator.

Example:

```java
public class MyValidator extends RangeStatusCodeValidator {

    public MyValidator() {}

      public MyValidator(String values) {
        setValues(values);
      }

      @Override
      public void validate(Result<InputStream, HttpResponseAttributes> result, HttpRequest request) {
        int status = result.getAttributes().get().getStatusCode();
        String method = request.getMethod();
        

        if ((!belongs(status)) && (!method.equals("GET"))) {
          throwValidationException(result, request, status);
        } 
      }
}
```

Then instantiate it in you flow and reference it in the response validator:

```xml
        <java:new doc:name="New" class="validator.MyValidator" constructor='MyValidator(String)' target="out">
            <java:args ><![CDATA[#[{arg0:"500"}]]]></java:args>
        </java:new>
        <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" responseValidator='#[vars.out]' path="/endpoint">
        </http:request>
```

Alternatively you can instance the class from DataWeave:

```xml
        <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" responseValidator='#[%dw 2.0 import java!validator::MyValidator output application/java --- MyValidator::new("500")]' path="/endpoint">
        </http:request>
```

Source: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-define-a-custom-HTTP-response-validator-in-Mule-Runtime-4-x

Comment: Is the source link correct?

Comment: Sorry, it was the wrong link. I fixed it.